# Modelling Ice cream/pop

Tags: modeling

i’m having difficulty modeling this icecream. for previous iterations of this, I could get away with making a basic modified circle and using a simple deform twist modifier but this is slightly more complex. Does anyone know how I could go about modeling this? Thank you :)
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a torus, in *Edit* mode rotate it on Y, move it away from its origin on Y:

[image]

Create an empty at the same location as the torus origin, give an *Array* modifier to the torus with the *Object Offset* option, choose the empty as *Object Offset*:

[image]

Rotate the empty on Z, choose a *Count* of 8 for the torus *Array*, in *Edit* mode rotate and fatten the torus as needed:

[image]

Give it a second *Array*, this time in *Relative Offset* mode, on Z:

[image]